# mentain textures proportion in shader

Tags: shader, cg-language

i have a shader that combines 2 textures in a given way.

How can i position the first texture in center of the second texture mentaining the corespondent proportions?

i.e. i have a image of 100x100 and another image 1024x 768. How can i combine the 2 textures so that the first image is centered in front of the second image, mentaining the difference between the images (not having the small image stretch through the whole material) ?

here is my shader:

```
 sampler2D _MainTex;
        sampler2D _MainTex2;

        float4 _Color;
        float _bwBlend;

        struct Input {
            float2 uv_MainTex;
            float2 uv_MainTex2;
        };

        void surf (Input IN, inout SurfaceOutput o) 
        {

            half4 c = tex2D(_MainTex, IN.uv_MainTex);
            half4 c2 = tex2D(_MainTex2, IN.uv_MainTex2);


        o.Normal =c.a > .2f ? (.1,.1,.1) : (0,0,0);
            o.Albedo = c.a > .2f ? c  : c2;
       }
```

The language is CG, but i think that anyone with more-than-basic knowledge of shaders can answer this question.

Answer (score 0):

i found an answer:

```
 void surf (Input IN, inout SurfaceOutput o) 
        {
        float2 a = IN.uv_MainTex*3 ;
            half4 c = tex2D(_MainTex, a);
            half4 c2 = tex2D(_MainTex2, IN.uv_MainTex2);

           // half lum = c.r*.3 + c.g*.59 + c.b*.11;
           // half3 bw = half3( lum, lum, lum );

         if(frac(IN.uv_MainTex.x) > .3f && frac(IN.uv_MainTex.x) < .7f && frac(IN.uv_MainTex.y) > .3f && frac(IN.uv_MainTex.y) < .7f)
         { 
            o.Normal =c.a > .2f ? (.1,.1,.1) : (0,0,0);
               o.Albedo = c.a > .2f ? c  : c2;
         }
         else
          {
          o.Normal = (0,0,0);
             o.Albedo = c2;
           }    

         }
```

I multiply the uvs for the small image, so that i get the image where i want it ( a 3x3 grid of the smaller image) . After that i "disable" the draw of the other non-centered images.